# Is it possible to list Registered Devices in Azure AD using azure-cli?

Tags: azure-cli

I was hoping for something similar to `az ad user list` or a method of finding the last logged on user with only a device name.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and clarify what you mean by **devices**.

Comment: Just rephrased 'devices registered in Azure AD' to 'Registered Devices'. Hopefully that makes more sense. If not, these bad boys: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-register

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can list Registered Devices in Azure AD using **Azure Powershell**.

```
Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice
   -ObjectId <String>
   [-All <Boolean>]
   [-Top <Int32>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

```
Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId  "df19e8e6-2ad7-453e-87f5-037f6529ae16"
```

You can refer to [Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduserregistereddevice?view=azureadps-2.0) and [List All Azure AD Registered Devices Using PowerShell](https://www.ntweekly.com/2021/07/01/list-all-azure-ad-registered-devices-using-powershell/)